# How to send MKCOL in Faraday?

Tags: ruby, webdav, faraday

In ruby built-in library Net::HTTP it's possible. In the code of Faraday there's no mention of MKCOL anywhere.

How to send MKCOL in Faraday?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a filter on the allowed http methods:

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/v0.15.3/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L15

You can make a call by doing:

```
Faraday::Connection::METHODS << :mkcol
f = Faraday.new('http://localhost:3000')
f.run_request(:mkcol, '/mypath', { 'param-foo' => 'test' }, { 'X-fake-header' => 'test' })
```

Comment: is this a monkey patch?